# set datasource for access report

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I have a .NET windows form project that uses access report, i would like to set access reports datasource from my .NET application
Now i have this code (below) that can show the report as PDF, but how can i set the datasource to my SQL query?
thanks

```
  Public Sub PrintAccess(filename As String, strsql As String, NameReportAcc As String)
 
    Dim StrPercorsoDb As String
    StrPercorsoDb = PathDBreg.GetValue("dbq")

    Dim oAccess As Access.Application
    oAccess = New Access.Application
    Dim sDBPath As String 'path to DB 

    sDBPath = StrPercorsoDb

    oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(filepath:=sDBPath, Exclusive:=False, bstrPassword:=PassDb)
    oAccess.DoCmd.Minimize()
    oAccess.Visible = False

    Try            
           oAccess.DoCmd.OpenReport(ReportName:="" & sReport & "", View:=Access.AcView.acViewPreview, FilterName:="", WhereCondition:="", WindowMode:=Access.AcWindowMode.acHidden, OpenArgs:="" & strsql & "")
        oAccess.DoCmd.OutputTo(Access.AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport, NameReportAcc , "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", FolderDB & "\" & filename, False)
    

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally

        oAccess.Quit()
        oAccess = Nothing
    End Try
```

end sub

Comment: How different are these queries?  Being a access report I'm guessing the basic structure of it is pretty consistant, so why not just build the report that outputs everything possible then use the WhereCondition to filter the results?

Comment: Yes, you're right, the problem is that some customers have macro disabled, and i need a way to set the query in access and let the report execute it

Comment: Maybe your better looking at one of the other reports suites, tools or techniques then.  Probably a better all round solution rather than relying on Access anyway

Comment: That said, if your requirement is having access installed so you can run it via interops why not just make it a requirement that macros are enabled?